# What happens if I don't use -g in linking time

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

Using gcc or clang, I used -g option for compilation and without it for linking. Does that mean that the final binary is equivalent in performance to the one without -g option in the whole compilation process?

Comment: I've never noticed any significant difference in performance when I use -g... in fact you can even use -g and -O, though the resulting binary might be tricky to step through in a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is considered a compiler bug if the performance of the binary with debugging information differs from the binary without. So, yes, you should expect the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

`-g` generates debugging information during the compile step; it is completely ignored by the linker. So what you're doing is equivalent to both compiling and linking in one step, using `-g`.